# Вывод всех твитов пользователя

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-api

Нужно через HTTP Вывести список всех твиттов пользователя @nettus и записать их в Excel файл с 2 ­мя колонками (Published Date, Message) и все это в виде консольной программы. С записью в Excel могу сам разобраться, а вот как стянуть все твиты и еще их даты мне не понятно, можете помочь ?

Comment: У [twitter есть API](https://dev.twitter.com/), вы его https://dev.twitter.com/ изучали? Вот например сходу нагуглилась статья для начинающих: https://habrahabr.ru/post/103548/

Comment: для того чтобы использовать api надо зарегистрировать приложение, а уменя обычный консольный скрипт

Comment: @АндрейШостик, а что, "обычный консольный скрипт" не приложение? Делов-то: регистрируете приложение, настраиваете разрешения, получаете ключ и вперёд.